# How to import reactjs code to react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, web-frontend

I have developed a webpage using react js and now want to develop the ios and Andriod app using react-native. How to import react js code to react-native?

Answer (score 1):

**React** is a framework for building applications using **JavaScript**. **React Native** is an **entire platform** allowing you to build native, cross-platform mobile apps, and React. You can't use the ReactJS in React, but you could connect to the backend of your app, made with ReactJS in React Native.

Comment: Can you help with any example or tutorial on how to connect backend of Reactjs to React Native.

Comment: You will have to learn Native too. Use one database for both, this is one way of connecting them.